# Make dynamic checkbox "checked" when id match

Tags: php, html, laravel

```
<div class="tab-content">
     @foreach($groups as $group)
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="grp-{{ $group->id }}">
                @foreach($ingreds as $ingred)
                       @if($ingred->id_ingredient_group==$group->id)
                           <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ingredients[]"  @foreach($item->ingredients as $ingredient)  @if($ingred->id==$ingredient->data->id) {{"checked"}} @endif   @endforeach  value="{{$ingred->id}}"> {{ $ingred->name}}
                           </label>

                       @endif
                 @endforeach
          </div>
     @endforeach
 </div>
```

I want if `"$ingred->id==$ingredient->data->id"` than my checkbox become checked but it is not happening.

Comment: Can you add more informations, like `$groups` example, to test it.
Also, what is your template engine with `@`?

Comment: Hello,
I don't see any error in your code. The best think you can do, it's debugging. Try to use `dd($var)` helper function. For example `@foreach($item->ingredients as $ingredient) <div>ID {{ $ingred->id }} equal to {{$ingredient->data->id}} ? {{dd($ingred)}} {{ dd($ingredient) }}</div> @endforeach`. @AnthonyB: It's framework lavarel, with Blade template engine

Comment: I tagged the answer as laravel. Thanks for this info @GeorgesO.

Comment: @ AnthonyB I have group of ingrdient(vegtable,fruit) as "groups" and ingreds are ingrdients of groups entity.

Comment: and ingredients is the element of group